# Prism 6 and constructor calling

Tags: mvvm, constructor, youtube, prism

Based from a video from Brian Lagunas ([YouTube Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZfBy2nfykqY)) I started using Prism 6. I am a little bit confused, where the constructor of the MainWindowViewModel is getting called. I nearly copied his project and can't find the part. If i set a break point in the constructor, it never gets there.

Was he no showing something in the video or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a look at the [code](https://github.com/brianlagunas/InfragisticsWebinarSimpleMVVMPrism/blob/master/PrismDemo/Views/MainWindow.xaml#L5) for this presentation, you can see that Brian is using Prism's attached dependency property to couple view and viewmodel through the ViewModelLocator.

```
prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
```

In the video around 33:00 he gives the full explanation how this ViewModelLocator works: first it builds the viewmodel name out of the view's name through convention. Then it either resolves this name to a type through an IoC container or reflection. IoC is pretty straight forward: give a type or name and it will give you an instance. For the reflection part (when you run without a container), Prism uses the [Activator type to create a new instance](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Prism/Mvvm/ViewModelLocationProvider.cs#L30).

In the final code available on GitHub, Brian is using Unity as IoC container. Custom mappings for his sub-views (ViewA/ViewB) are made in the Bootstrapper. As there is no custom mapping for MainViewModel, following process happens:

- The app starts with MainWindow as the startup window.
- The attached property for the ViewModelLocator gets 'triggered', internal logic will map from MainWindow to MainWindowViewModel
- As we're using Unity, the ViewModelLocator asks for an instance of the viewmodel
- Unity will create a new MainWindowViewModel object and the constructor will get hit

So you won't see new  xxxViewModel() in code, but it does get created. This means you have much greater flexibility over hardcoded object creation when it comes down to adding dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the link with the sourcecode. My small application works now :)
I changed that the ViewModel of the viewA inside the MainWindow is now linked, instead of just the MainWindow